# Tomcat: see what threads are using the database connection pool

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, apache-commons-dbcp

Tomcat has a database connection pool (DBCP) to make requests faster.

In my app, too many connections are being used for too long, I suspect a leak (connection not being properly closed) and I need to find out where is the leak.

QUESTION: How to find out the name of each thread which is using a connection?

Preferably live JMX MBean, but other tips are welcome too. Showing each thread's stack trace or class name would be acceptable too.

*Note: I am not looking for an MBean that shows the DBCP settings. I want to see what uses each connection.*

Answer (score 8):

Such a bean unfortunately does not exist.

What you *can* do is enable the `logAbandoned` setting in your DBCP configuration. Look at the documentation for Apache Commons-DBCP ( http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) for details: you can use all of the configuration options there in your `<Resource>` element in Tomcat.

`logAbandoned` will tell you where a Connection was checked-out of the pool that wasn't returned in a timely way. That can indicate a Connection leak, or just queries that are long-running.

**UPDATE 2015-12-15**

With Tomcat's [`tomcat-pool`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), you can attach interceptors such as the [SlowQueryReport](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport) or, to get notifications via JMX, [SlowQueryReportJmx](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReportJmx)

These tools might be able to do a better job than the more basic information you can get back from Apache Commons-DBCP.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip! I created a tool based on this idea, please see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Tipped by Christopher's answer, I created a tool to monitor borrowed/released connections:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Commons-DBCP-monitoring

It monitors Commons DBCP usage and allows one to create such graphs:

[image]

[image]

It makes it super easy to identify which threads are holding connections for a long time.

Comment: Would you consider refactoring your solution so that the pool itself is queryable instead of writing to `stdout`? If you do that, you could donate it back to the Tomcat project and get your name in the changelog.